# Is it possible to partition the hard-disk with Java code in Windows

Tags: java, windows

I'm trying to write some tests to a Windows App.

I write the tests with Java and as part of one of the test I want to partition the hard-disk.

My question is:

Can Java code can do something like this or this is something that can be done only via Windows itself.

If it cannot be done with java: how I can bypass it with Java (maybe .bat script that java can trigger or something like this)

Comment: Java can't do it itself, instead, you'd execute a external command to do it (preferably a CLI), maybe start with a google for something like [windows partition disk cli](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=windows+partion+disk+cli&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) to figure out the command line requirements.  Then you need to explore `ProcessBuilder` which will allow you to execute the CLI and read back any output it might produce

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Do you maybe why java cannot do it? Java can do only things that the OSs owner let it do? (there is no API to the hard-disk drive partitioning, but to files and etc.  )

Comment: Because it's not a feature that could be easily abstracted for - it's a OS specific feature and one which is likely privileged.  If you're really in for some hard ball, you could try using JNI/JNA to make some low level APIs via the winapis, but, to be honest, why not just use the CLI.  Also, I'd consider this a "dangerous" API which is best not exposed to every developer out there, especially with the Log4J exploit which exists right now. You also have to remember that some of the disk formats are proprietary, so there's probably also licensing issues on top of it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible via CLI commands. Example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c diskpart");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c select disk 0");
```

But you should know true disk partition commands. You can look this page: https://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/Using-Diskpart-to-create-extend-or-delete-a-disk-partition

Comment: I know that java can be exposed to the OS's CLI, but the question relates to if Java can do it with Java classes. (in the same way that if you want to create a file in the file system you don't need to use the CLI - but you can create a new instance of the File class and give it a path)